# cakephp multilingual routes

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, routes, multilingual

I'm working on a **multilingual website** and I want to create **multilingual routes**.

example:

**monsite.com/en/the-house**, **monsite.com/fr/la-maison** and **monsite.com/it/la-casa** link to the "**house**" action of the "**pages**" controller

**monsite.com/en/leisures**, **monsite.com/fr/loisirs** and **monsite.com/it/tempo-libero** to action "**leisures**" of the "**pages**" controller...

that's my route:

```
Router::connect('/:lang/'.__("the-house"),
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'house'),
    array('lang' => '[a-z-]{2}')
);
```

i find a "**manuel**" solution but i want to do it "**automatically**"

```
Router::connect('/:lang/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'house'),
    array('lang' => '[a-z-]{2}', 'slug' => 'la-maison|the-house|la-casa')
);
```

thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the `lang` variable in router configuration and check this variable in your controller at `beforeFilter()` event.

For example:

```
Router::connect('/:lang/:slug', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'), array('slug' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 'lang' => 'en|fr|it', 'pass' => array('slug', 'lang')));
```

And in your controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if (isset($this->request->params['lang'])) {
        // do what you want with your language variable.
        // Like setting Config.language or set your models locale property, etc.
    }
}
```

Or uber-manual way:

```
public function view($slug = null, $lang = null) {
    switch ($lang) {
        case 'en': /* locale is english */ break;
        case 'fr': /* locale is french */ break;
    }    
}
```

For reverse routing (ie, when using `$this->Html->link()` in your views), you need to pass `lang` parameter to routing array to make your link for your locale.

And also, it's better to use `Translate` behaviour and `i18n` tables to work on multi language records for your models easily.

Little warning: CakePHP uses 3 letter ISO codes for locales internally, like 'eng', 'ger', 'fra'.